# Game Optimization

Tags: linear-algebra, game-theory

I stumbled over this problem while coding and I'm lost. Is there a simple solution to this problem? Or what terms do I have to look for to read up on it?

**Game rules**

- you have *n* cards (e.g. **A** & **B**) which you have to place onto *n* playing fields (e.g. **I** & **II**). One card per field and all cards have to be placed.
- you gain points according to a card/ playing field table. For example:

\begin{array}{c|c|c}
 & I & II \\\hline
A & 1 & 2 \\\hline
B & -1 & 2 
\end{array}

- the goal is to gain the maximum points possible.

  => In this example it'd be **A** => **I**, **B** => **II** for 3 points.

What is the best way of finding the optimal combination as fast as possible in the general case?

e.g. *n* = 3 {**A, B, C, I, II, III**}

\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 3\\-1 & 4 & 2\\1 & 4 & 3 \end{bmatrix}

edit: Ok the problem is known as the assignment problem (https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/149595/maximum-sum-of-values-in-a-square-grid-one-in-each-row-column)

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Currently brute forcing for 3 dimensions which is only 6 possible combinations. Though this might cause problems once I go for higher dimensions...